# How to click a button on a website using Puppeteer without any class, id ,... assigned to it?

Tags: html, node.js, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

So I want to click on a button on a website. The button has no id, class,... So I should find a way to click the button with the name that's on it. In this example I should click by the name "Supreme®/The 
    North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag"

This is my code in Node.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let scrape = async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/bags');
await page.click(...);
browser.close();
return result;
};
```

This is the element that I want to click:

```
<a class="name-link" href="/shop/bags/a9cz4te2r/rsth86fbl">Supreme®/The 
North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag</a>
```

Comment: Could not find any such `name-link` class or this name `Supreme®/The 
North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag` in the landing page. Where did you get this?

Comment: I got it from this link: https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/bags. And Then the first bag on the second row, it under the <article> tag then under <h1>

Comment: Is this the url `https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/bags/dd3wmsh9x/a05ivugj2` connected to that bag? If it is, you picked the wrong elements.

Comment: That link doesn't work for me. I guess it is because you are from an other part of the world.

Comment: I've provided a selector below based on your elements above. Just use that within the script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way to collect that data. Try these on your browsers console first.

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('a.name-link')]
.filter(element => 
  element.innerText.includes('Supreme®/The North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag')
)
```

What's going on here?

- `document.querySelectorAll` finds all element with that selector.
- `.filter` will return the result that matches the query.
- `.includes` will return data that includes a given string.

If `a.name-link` does not work, then look for `a`, if that does not work, then find the parent item and use that.

Once you got the element on your browser, you can apply that on your code, click it etc.

## Usage:

You can use `page.evaluate` to filter and click.

```
const query = "Supreme®/The North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag";

page.evaluate(query => {
  const elements = [...document.querySelectorAll('a.name-link')];

  // Either use .find or .filter, comment one of these
  // find element with find
  const targetElement = elements.find(e => e.innerText.includes(query));

  // OR, find element with filter
  // const targetElement = elements.filter(e => e.innerText.includes(query))[0];

  // make sure the element exists, and only then click it
  targetElement && targetElement.click();
}, query)
```

Comment: propably a silly question but i'm kind of new to this but what do these 3 points mean before document?

Comment: That's a spread operator. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: As I asked above, can you share a screenshot of the page you are trying to access? Otherwise share the source code of that page somewhere. Otherwise it's all just guessing what works etc.

Comment: I removed that accepted thing by accident, because your code works. . Btw this is the link https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/bags

Comment: No, I am not talking about the link, it's about the screenshot. It doesn't show here like you are seeing. I tried with proxies too. Just doesn't show any name anywhere.

Comment: I just guessed what you were trying to do and provided a solution based on that.

Comment: This is what I see: http://prntscr.com/l8bhwh
This is the element that I need to click on : http://prntscr.com/l8bioh
But as you can see there are also multiple colors: http://prntscr.com/l8bivx
I need to select the right colour too. Thanks

Comment: Ah so Supreme shows that data for london. Great. The above snippet should work perfectly. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, the following piece of code should let you click on that link:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all/bags');
await page.click("a[href$='a05ivugj2']");
await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Btw, If the elements available from your end are in reality what you have pasted above then replace this portion `page.click("a[href$='a05ivugj2']")` with `page.click("a[href$='rsth86fbl']")` from within my script above.

Comment: If I change the href$ to ckf2cimj7 it will work for me. I guess this is because the website works regional. But the problem is I wont be able to get that tag before the item goes online. The only thing I will know before it goes online is the name of the item. So I need to find a way to click the link by the name "Supreme®/The North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag".

Comment: The name you mentioned is not available in that page (at least from my end) when I search it through chrome dev tools.

Comment: It is the name of the item itself. http://prntscr.com/l8ahbr and http://prntscr.com/l8ahwc

Comment: This is how I can see [check out this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/q4zvpt09pus04na/Untitled.jpg?dl=0).

Comment: ok, that's weird. But do you got any idea how I can click the link only using the name of the item with the screenshots I gave you?

Comment: As `.querySelector()` doesn't support pseudo-selectors, you need to avail `xpath` to click on that link defining ***`.='Supreme®/The North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag'`*** within it.

Answer (score 0):

The following function will click the first element that matches certain text:

```
const clickText = text => {
    return page.evaluate(text => [...document.querySelectorAll('*')].find(e => e.textContent.trim() === text).click(), text);
};
```

You can use the function in your Puppeteer script using the following method:

```
await clickText('Supreme®/The North Face® Leather Shoulder Bag');
```

Comment: I get ```cannot read property click of undefined```