# How to make a click on a button that doesnt have id on pupeteer

Tags: javascript, button, puppeteer, cart

I'm working on a bot that buy by himself, but after he put the Credit card, exp and cvv, the page has a button that doesn't have id, only have class, the code of the button is

`<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block submit_silentOrderPostForm checkout-next">Siguiente</button>`

I'm trying with

`await page.click('#btn btn-primary btn-block submit_silentOrderPostForm checkout-next')`

and with

`await page.click('btn btn-primary btn-block submit_silentOrderPostForm checkout-next')`

but it doesn't work. How may I do it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to click a button on a website using Puppeteer without any class, id ,... assigned to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52904802/how-to-click-a-button-on-a-website-using-puppeteer-without-any-class-id-as)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Page.click`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&show=api-pageclickselector-options) requires a CSS selector as its mandatory parameter. Do not forget that [CSS class selector syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) is: `.class-name`, so you will need something like this:

```js
await page.click('.btn.btn-primary.btn-block.submit_silentOrderPostForm.checkout-next')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a unique class name like **mybutton** or whatever and add it to that button.

```
<button type="submit" class="mybutton btn btn-primary btn-block submit_silentOrderPostForm checkout-next">Siguiente</button>
```

Call it like this:

```
 await page.click('mybutton')
```

I hope that gives you an idea.

Comment: That's not what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the element with a query selector that checks as much info as you have, like this...

```
var B=document.querySelectorAll('button[type="submit"][class*="submit_silentOrderPostForm"]')[0];


B.style.color='red'; // It works! :)
```